# Only one ImageButton showing up under findViewById()

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on a project with ImageButtons to navigate to different pages. Whenever I try to refer to the home button using `findViewById(R.id.HomeButton)` , it works, but when I try to do it for any of the other buttons, the IDs never show up. `HomeButton` is the only one that works. Any solutions?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/homebutton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/home"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#44ba52"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/MapButton"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mapbutton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/map"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#44ba52"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/MenuButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/MenuButton"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/MenuButton"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menubutton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#44ba52"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean -> Rebuild and Invalidate Restart your system. All buttons should work as HomeButton. and Make sure your application doesn't have any type of error.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.Rebuild your project.

Option 2. use ButterKnife library instead of findViewById.

1.)import this library.
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

2) @BindView(R.id.HomeButton)
    ImageButton homebtn;

```
@BindView(R.id.MenuButton)
ImageButton menubtn;

@BindView(R.id.MapButton)
ImageButton mapbtn;
```

After that bind the imageButton in oncreate() method...
 3) ButterKnife.bind(this);